# Having trouble getting a background image to cover full width of screen

Tags: css, background-image

I want to have a background image to fill the entire width of the screen (not the height though) like on these websites: http://www.rokivo.com/ and
https://teemo.gg/

My current structure looks like this:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

  <div class="container">
    Code for header
  </div>

</header>

<div class="container">
  Rest of page contents here
</div>
```

Am I going to have to wrap everything else in a div with class container and use that to specify the background-image? Or is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

HTML:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

  <div class="header-content">
    Code for header
  </div>

</header>

<div class="container">
  Rest of page contents here
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/2000/1000/?blur) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header-content {
  padding: 5em 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

So what's going on here? The wrapping header has a width of 100% in order to cover the entire width of the screen and has a background image as well. Also, it's set to no-repeat and centered vertically/horizontally, as well as background-size set to cover to allow as much of the image to show as possible.

On the .header-content, a padding is added to the div so that it is vertically centered.

The padding, text size, etc can be adjusted, but this should give you a general idea of how this effect is accomplished.

To see it in action, see this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAmzdA).

Comment: Is there a way to make it so the background image covers not only the header, but also some of the content as well like in the teemo.gg web page, it covers the header, as well as main logo + search bar. Or will I just have to wrap everything in a div to achieve this?

Comment: Exactly, you would need to wrap everything in that header-content div that's within the header.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something simple like:

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <!-- nav stuff -->
    </nav>
  <div class="main-container">
    Code for header
  </div>

</header>

<div class="container">
  Rest of page contents here
</div>

.main-container {
    background: url(htts://someimage.com/1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;  // or like the teemo site - height: 500px;
}
```

here's a good read on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)